# Share mouse to linux from windows

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, mouse, multi-monitor

Quick overview of my setup:

[image]

Where:

1: Raspberry Pi

2: 2nd Monitor for Windows 7 Laptop

3: Windows 7 Laptop

4: 2nd Monitor for Linux (Ubuntu) laptop

5: Linux Laptop

I would like to share my keyboard and mouse across all monitors.

I'm not overly concerned about the clipboard, however it would be a plus.

I do not want to spend any money.

Mouse is wired, to windows laptop (#3)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How's the mouse connected (USB/BT/…) and to which machine (I guess #3 is it)? Not that I know a software solution, but this might be a criterium.

Comment: Which OS is the Raspberry Pi running, Raspbian?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/)

[image: Synergy splash]

Synergy allows to share a keyboard and mouse across several computers. Basically, you install it on all your computers.

The one with the mouse and keyboard is the server, everything else is a client. You can configure the screen disposition and pass the mouse from a screen to the other by going over the edge.

[image: Configuration]

### Requirements

- Share keyboard and mouse: Yes
- Clipboard: Yes
- <s>Free</s>: It was, in the far past. Today, for a single user, it's $10 for a lifetime license
- Multi-monitor: Yes, but can be a pain depending on the disposition. Yours should work fine. (You configure a computer in the server view, not a single screen)
- Compatibility:

  - Windows: Yes
  - Ubuntu: Yes
  - Raspberry: Unsure